# Golang encode float to JSON with specified precision

Tags: go

We can print a float number with specified precision like this:

`fmt.Printf("%.2f", num)`

Can we do the same when encode float to JSON?

So that for num = 0.1234,

we can get {"num": 0.12} instead of {"num": 0.1234} .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom type with a custom marshal function.  You may want to implement a custom unmarshaling function as well.

```golang
type LPFloat struct {
    Value  float32 // the actual value
    Digits int     // the number of digits used in json
}

func (l LPFloat) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.*f", l.Digits, l.Value)
    return []byte(s), nil
}
```

[Here is a working example on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CS4F8bYU-63).

See also the examples in the [`encoding/json` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

Edit: `strconv.FormatFloat`, as in [josssefaz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811599/1256452), will generally be more efficient than `fmt.Sprintf`.  Unless this is a bottleneck that shows up in profiling, you should use whichever one you find clearer.

Comment: Thanks @torek for the comments ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the strconv.FormatFloat method :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)


type RoundedFloat float64

type RoundIt struct {
    Num RoundedFloat
}


func main() {
    data, _:= json.Marshal(RoundIt{ 0.1234})
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
#Implement your own MarshalJSON func
func (r RoundedFloat) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        return []byte(strconv.FormatFloat(float64(r), 'f', 2, 32)), nil
}
```

Output :

`{"Num": 0.12}`

On go playground : [Click here](https://play.golang.org/p/IYTlvd6nd7X)